# PHP date and time issue

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

In php I set

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
```

My system timezone is `(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi`

Both are same.
But when  I change the system date and time , the PHP returns the same date and time as sytem date and time .
ie) When I set system time as **2013-07-10 11:00:00**, then 
PHP date function returns the same date time as **2013-07-10 11:00:00**. But the actual time is different.
 I want the actual date and time from php not system date and time.
How can I implement this? If you have any idea please share.

Comment: Are you working on localhost or on server?

Comment: the place this is fixed is on the server, there are measures that can be taken to sync the server time up with a ntp server, There should never be any reason to do this in php

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ Localhost

Comment: @Nandu your machine is working as a server that time and in your machine you have set the time and the timezone Culcutta, I think so, that's why your code it detecting that and show the time which you are set in machine. on server this will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are working on local host, the PHP take the current time and date from the local system settings. 
When you hosted in internert it will work properly.